# Should these buttons disappear once clicked?

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

I just noticed these buttons in the sidebar,

<kbd>[image: This]</kbd>

and when I click on then, the questions change, but the buttons also disappear until I refresh the page.

Is this intended behaviour, as it seems a bit strange them just going away.

Windows 10 on Chrome 49.0.2623.87

Comment: They have to do with the new-nav, there were a few changes last night which moved this.  The design team is checking it.

Comment: Related, [why are they even there?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320045/476716)

Comment: @OrangeDog They are part of the new navigation and typically are located in a [different place](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing)

Comment: @bluefeet, when you say "typically located in a different place", do you mean that the fact that they're in the "Featured on Meta" box is a bug, along with the disappearing behavior? Or is that placement something that's being tested? Because it feels very weird for them to be there, if it's a deliberate test.

Comment: @sphanley If you check the link, you'll notice that the boxes should appear in a different location in the new-nav but due to some CSS changes last night it moved.  The design team is working on correcting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. We're currently trying to consolidate and organize some of our CSS and one of the classes used by this menu toggle was placed in the wrong place. This has been fixed and should be corrected now on production.