# What are these buttons doing here?

Tags: bug, user-interface

[image: Screenshot with freehand circle]

I assumed they would change the featured box in some way, but actually changed the layout of the main questions list.
Surely they should be moved somewhere else?

Comment: Pretty much a dup of the other one. It has to do with the new-nav, it's in the process of being fixed.

Comment: I like the circle better on this one. The other one looks like a speech bubble.